# Mangoose Nested Find not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, mean-stack

This is my model:

```
UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
    username: string,
    password: string,
    records: Record[]
};
Record: {
    name: string;
    date: Date;
}
```

Query:

```
    const date = new Date();
    const lastDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    UserModel.find({ "records" : { "$elemMatch": {  "date" : { "$gte": lastDate } } }}, (err, userRecords: any) => {
     if (err) {
         return res.json({
             "status": "error",
             "detail": err
         });
     }
     return res.json({
         "records": userRecords
     });
   });
```

This query returns all records, rather than records just from last 30 days. I am unable to locate where I am going wrong.

Edit: Even after using "lastDate.toISOString()" inplace of "lastDate" above, I still get all the results back.

Edit: Tested few other solution, like using "$filter", but still I get all records back.

Comment: `.find()` queries do not "filter" the array content returned. That task belongs to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: Check the format in which the `date` is stored in `Records` document. In Mongo if filter conditions for fields are not matching the format, it returns entire collection

Comment: @Abhishek its stored as format Date in document

Comment: If you can't help, it fine.You don't need to be vigil anti. I did try whatever you posted as duplicate, and it didn't work. Looks at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date to ISO format in which it stored in DB then it will work.

Comment: After doing this change "{ "$gte": lastDate.toISOString() }", now I get no records back.  Any care needs to be taken while saving dates as well to make sure this works ?

Comment: what's date format saved in db?

Comment: its ISO date format

Comment: ok.. instead of '.toISOString()' use moment(lastDate).format();